# Call a Model method using Laravel Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model, relationship

I'm currently trying to use Laravel Relationships to access my achievements Model using User model, I use this relationship code:

```
public function achievements()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User\Achievement');
}
```

I can easily make some eloquent queries, however I can't access any method that I created there, I can't access this method:

```
class Achievement extends Model
{
    public function achievementsAvailableToClaim(): int
    {
        // Not an eloquent query
    }
}
```

Using the following code:

```
Auth::user()->achievements()->achievementsAvailableToClaim();
```

I believe that I am using this Laravel function in the wrong way, because of that I tried something else without using relationship:

```
public function achievements()
{
    return new \App\Models\User\Achievement;
}
```

But that would have a performance problem, because would I be creating a new class instance every time I use the achievements function inside user model?

What would be the right way of what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not working because your eloquent relationship is a hasMany so it return a collection. you can not call the related model function from a collection.

you can var dump it on tinker to understand more what i mean.

Comment: What if I return a manually made collection from that method?

Comment: change your function implement to this and you should be good to go. 
public function scopeAchievementsAvailableToClaim()
{
   return $query->where('achivement_avilable', true);
}

For further information check this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel [scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#local-scopes).Like local scopes allow you to define common sets of constraints that you may easily re-use throughout your application.

In your case you use this like, Define scope in model:

```
public function scopeAchievementsAvailableToClaim()
{
   return $query->where('achivement_avilable', true);
}
```

And you can use this like :

```
Auth::user()->achievements()->achievementsAvailableToClaim();
```

Comment: This would not work since the achievementsAvailableToClaim() is not an eloquent query.